# Unittesting- how to test if a calculation is right for each iteration of a loop?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Basically, how to test for/while loops. Is this even a thing? Should I just test the output of the calculation and see if thats correct?

this code is below. its a function that runs a template over a (larger) image.

```
def _scan_image(self, image, template, process):
     """main function: will iterate over the image one pixel at a time"""


     for i in xrange(len(image)): # --------> I want to test inside this loop
      for j in xrange(len(image[i])):
        if (j <= self.x_axis_leng) and \
          (i <= self.y_axis_hgt):

          self.temp_matrix_holder.append(\
            image[i][j:j+len(template[0])])

          self.temp_matrix_holder.append(\
            image[i + 1][j:j+len(template[0])])



          new_score = self.calculate.run(\
            self.temp_matrix_holder, self.temp, process)


          if new_score <= self.score:
            self.score = new_score
            self.best_location = [j, i]

        self._empty_list()


    return self.score, self.best_location
```

Comment: *Personally*, I've rarely found testing the internals of a method interesting or worth the time of building the test, and testing only the output (possibly with more robust test cases) is sufficient.  This is especially true in the case that the method internals might be later refactored rendering your tests a waste.